# Is there a way to add a third toggle option to an on/off state by .onLongPressGesture?

Tags: swiftui

I already have a toggle set up as in the image below to toggle the image on/off or pass / fail.
I am trying to add a third state using a long press gesture to the image which will turn the image grey with a slash icon.
I have achieved this in the text element as at is doesn't have an bool condition, but after much searching can't figure out how to achieve this with the image.

What I am aiming for is something along the lines of:

```
Image(systemName: isPressed ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "x.circle.fill" || isLongPressed ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "slash.circle.fill")
```

Though I know this is not correct.

```
struct element: View {
    var section: CleaningElements = courseSections[0]
    
    @State private var isPressed = true
    @State private var isLongPressed = true
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            Button(action: {
                    self.isPressed.toggle() }) {
                Image(systemName: isPressed ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "x.circle.fill")
                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                    .foregroundColor(isPressed ? .green : .red)
                    .frame(width: 36, height: 36)
                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12, style: .continuous).fill(section.color))
            }
            Text(section.title)
                .font(.subheadline)
                .bold()
                .opacity(isLongPressed ? 1.0 : 0.3)
                .foregroundColor(isLongPressed ? Color.primary : Color.secondary)
                .onLongPressGesture {
                    self.isLongPressed.toggle()
                }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(3)
    }
}
```

[image: On/Off, or N/A states]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo (with simplified your code) of possible solution - keep button for highlight but actions handle but custom gestures. Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

[image: demo]

```
struct element: View {
    
    @State private var isPressed = false
    @State private var isLongPressed = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {}) {
            Group {
                if isLongPressed {
                    Image(systemName: "minus.circle")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                } else {
                    Image(systemName: isPressed ? "checkmark.circle.fill" : "x.circle.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(isPressed ? .green : .red)
                }
            }
            .font(.system(size: 20))
            .frame(width: 36, height: 36)
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12, style: .continuous).fill(Color.yellow))
            .gesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
                isLongPressed = false
                self.isPressed.toggle()
            })
            .gesture(LongPressGesture().onEnded { _ in
                isLongPressed = true
            })
        }
    }
}
```