# How can I have tap and LongPressGesture on a Button in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I am trying implement to kind of tap on a Button, the first one would be the normal tap of Button which works automatically by itself without coding, when I want add a LongPressGesture to that Button, it would not get recognised as a LongPressGesture, I think it because of build it tap Gesture of Button, how can I have both gesture work together?

```
Button(action: {
                
   print("you just tapped me!")
                
}, label: {
                
   Text("tap me!")

})
.onLongPressGesture() {

   print("you just LongPressed me!")

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64953999/12299030?

Comment: if I understood right, I should not use  action of Button in this case, right? and I should add TapGesture to codes. is that ok?

Comment: @Asperi: I looked that Link, and edited my codes, but still not working. could you see that?

Comment: @mimi You need to put gestures *inside* the button, i.e. attach them to `Text` instead of `Button`.

Comment: @pawello2222: ok, thanks, that was good help